# Create local network with Virtual Machine on remote Hyper-V Server

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2012, windows-networking

I try to describe situation as well as I can.

I have a dedicated server on http://www.hetzner.de/

- I've installed there Windows Server 2012
- set up Hyper-V role
- created new virtual machine with default external virtual switch that share my NIC (I have only 1 NIC)
- configure IP address on VM (without manual configure network was undefined)

### Now I have:

- Host Server with one static IP without any domen
- I can connect Server by RDC.
- VM on Host that I can use only from Host (i describe it later)
- I even turn off firewall (for test phase i want to ping my server)

Screenshots [(i can't upload images)](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3302BD30FA4D7D41!331) :

- virtual switch configuration
- Server ipconfig /all
- VM network config
- client ipconfig /all

### Problems

- VM can't get internet Access (it can't get auto configs from DHCP and I can't connect to DNS Server even though I try all possible IP that I saw and use DNS suffix)
- I can't connect to Hyper-V Server by Hyper-V Manager (but it's not what i want in first place)

### I want

I want to create a local network (edit: i mean virtual) where I could see VM's on my Server from my remote computer and could connect to Vm's by RDC.

Is it possible?
If it possible can you give me instructions?
Should I use outsource administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. My provider has binding to MAC addresses. The reality that I didn't need to manually configure NIC's settings. But I had to get virtual MAC address to my external IP and set it in settings of NIC (I did it in my virtualizaion program not inside virtual machine).